# Facebook Ads API Insights: Not receiving `dda_results` in Ads Insights API response

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graphql

I am using the Facebook Ads API to pull Ads Insights data for my campaigns. I am trying to include `dda_results` in the data I fetch, which according to the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-insights/) should contain "Estimated incremental conversions caused by a given ad".

Here's the API query I am using:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_XXXX/insights?level=ad&fields=campaign_name,campaign_id,adset_name,adset_id,ad_name,ad_id,clicks,reach,impressions,objective,spend,inline_link_clicks,dda_results&limit=500&time_increment=1&access_token=XXXX&time_range[since]=2023-09-10&time_range[until]=2023-09-21](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_XXXX/insights?level=ad&fields=campaign_name,campaign_id,adset_name,adset_id,ad_name,ad_id,clicks,reach,impressions,objective,spend,inline_link_clicks,dda_results&limit=500&time_increment=1&access_token=XXXX&time_range%5Bsince%5D=2023-09-10&time_range%5Buntil%5D=2023-09-21)

The API returns the other fields I have requested (like `campaign_name`, `adset_name`, etc.) but `dda_results` comes up empty.

What I have checked:

- DDA is enabled for the campaigns
- The access token has necessary permissions
- The campaign objectives should support DDA data

Why am I not receiving any data in `dda_results`, and how can I resolve this issue?

I executed the above API query expecting to receive `dda_results` as part of the JSON response, along with the other fields like `campaign_name` and `adset_name`. While I successfully received data for all the other specified fields, the `dda_results` field came up empty in the response. I expected `dda_results` to contain estimated incremental conversions as per the Facebook documentation.

I have verified that DDA is enabled for my campaigns, my access token has the necessary permissions, and my campaign objectives should be compatible with DDA data. Despite this, I'm not receiving any data in the `dda_results` field.